# Why I cant access internet even if I have connected to WiFi and my ipconfig is disabled?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, internet-connection, malware, network-adapter

Recently my Windows 8 PC got infected by some adware, and my windows defender got disabled. Somehow, I managed to perform a system restore, and I have disabled two services, which I found causing problems, `BIT` and `Kitty`. The adware was creating unwanted online game shortcuts in my Taskbar and Desktop. After system restore, McAfee LiveSafe (I installed to remove malware) became un responsive and I removed it using Mc Afee product removal tool. Beore that, my internet connection became blocked. I was able to browse internet before system restore, but now, even if I am connected to my WiFi, I am unable to browse using IE or FF. I checked my Internet options LAN settings, and there are no proxy servers set. When I type `ipconfig` in cmd (both in normal and admin modes), it is sowing just a single line `Windows IP configuration` and nothing below that. I was using [DNS Jumper](http://www.sordum.org/7952/dns-jumper-v2-1/) for quickly switching DNS, and I was able to see my adapters listed in it. But now, I can see no adapter listed in it. I have tried `ipconfig /release` and getting the error;

```
The operation failed as no adapter is in the state permissible for this operation.
```

I have tried the answer in [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/the-operation-failed-as-no-adapter-is-in-the-state/39ab2c22-e64e-45eb-b8d8-0e40768ee0a9), but still I am unable to access internet. I have tried homegroup and internet trouble shootings, but no use. Somebody kindly help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like it's time to reinstall Windows.  If your not being assigned an up address (evident of the error output) you won't be able to visit external up addresses nor internal up addresses either

Comment: Is there any fix??